# Phusion Passenger fails to compile on CentOS

Tags: apache-2.2, phusion-passenger

I'm trying to install Phusion passenger (aka mod_rails) for the default Apache2 install on a CentOS 5.9 box.  I successfully installed the gem using the following, `sudo gem install passenger` but when I go to run the next command, `sudo passenger-install-apache2-module` I get a warning stating that my system doesn't have enough memory, but I can continue with the install.  It then proceeds to begin the compile of Phusion Passenger but then fails.

Is there a place I can check to see specifically why the compile is failing?

Comment: The output that was on your screen, to begin with.

Comment: the output gave me a directory listing to the user guide.

Answer (score 0):

The reason Phusion Passenger would not compile was due to lack of memory on the VPS.  I ended up creating a VM on my local machine, and installing all the same components, then compiling passenger on the VM, finally transferring the passenger gem to the VPS.